# Encrypted data transfer with middle node and asymmetric key

Tags: cryptography, asymmetric

I'm looking forward to pass data from a node `A` to a node `B` using [asymmetric cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography), but with one (huge) constraint: When `A` sends data to `B`, it is possible that `B` is offline. I would like to be able to read the message as soon as `B` came online, even if `A` is not online any longer.

It is not a problem to add other number of nodes online 24/7, **as long as the servers can't read the message sent from `A` to `B`**

Is there a way to achieve this? How?

Comment: I'm new here and not a security expert, so please feel free to edit my question using the correct terms (not sure if node is a correct term) and the tags. Thanks!

Comment: Have you thought of email, sftp, connect direct, in fact any form of asynchronous communication which supports encryption.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Can I send you an encrypted e-mail without changing a symmetric key with you that my e-mail server will not be able to read? Or any of the other options? How? (This is the question basically)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the model of encrypted emails. So see [OpenPGP](http://www.openpgp.org/), in particular its open-source implementation [GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/). With your notations, node B has a public/private key pair, and node A knows the public key of B. Node A asymmetrically encrypts the message with node B's public key, and only node B can decrypt it, using its private key, which no other node knows. When A sends the message, it actually sends it to some repository server (B's "mailbox"), which B will consult when it goes online again. The repository does not have a copy of B's private key, and therefore cannot decrypt the message.

For the *encryption* process, node A only needs a copy of B's public key, which is *public*, and does not change; node A can use B's public to encrypt one billion successive messages without any security problem. B's public key does not "wear off" upon usage. Node B needs not be online at any point for the encryption to work.

There are a lot of tricky details to care of when designing a format for asymmetric encryption, so you are warmly encouraged *not* to do it, and instead rely on some existing protocol (like OpenPGP) which has been thoroughly reviewed by many cryptographers. Similarly, *implementation* is also a dangerous part, and you cannot test for involuntary data leaks, so reusing some existing code is also a smart move.

The hard part in asymmetric encryption is how to make sure that what node A considers to be "B's public key" is really the public key of B, not a fake public key whose corresponding private key is known to the attacker. Depending on your context, this "making sure" part can be as simple as a one-time configuration, or as complex as a full-blown [PKI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_infrastructure).